# Automating 3rd Party Windows App

Tags: windows, automation

I want to automate the use of a 3rd party Windows application that I use frequently. I have found numerous automation applications that track key strokes and mouse movements which work fine for the most part but there is one difficulty, outlined below.

I launch the app, click on a button called "Add Files" and a second window pops up where I navigate to a directory, highlight some files and click "Open" which then returns to the original window. The problem is that the files I am opening vary wildly in size, meaning that sometimes when I click Open, the original window will have focus (is ready for further instructions) again in 2 seconds, other times I have to wait over a minute for focus to return.

This is difficult to automate as I'd like. Clicking anything if the files have not fully loaded causes "Not Responding" errors. I could get around this by setting a very high wait time in whatever automation application I choose, but if the file sizes are small and focus is returned to the original window quickly, I would rather not wait...!

So, can anyone suggest an automation application (paid or otherwise) that would know when focus has returned to the original application and further input could be accepted? If not, would it be possible to do this through some other method in Windows? Thank you for any pointers in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use AutoIT ( www.autoitscript.com ). It's a freeware scripting language but can also be compiled into an executable, and it's commonly used to automate windows tasks.
You can use the WinWaitActive function ( http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinWaitActive.htm ) to pause execution until a window gains focus.

If that is still too early, you may be able to detect changes in the window that happen after the file has been processed (status messages, buttons changing state, the filename appearing in a listbox...) and use that as a signal that the program is ready and that the script can continue.